# To checkout on to a branch which contains '&' in its name

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a branch with the name **yard&park**. When I try to use this command

```
git checkout yard&park
```

it shows me following error

```
[1] 22471
error: pathspec 'yard' did not match any file(s) known to git.
No command 'park' found, did you mean:
 Command 'parl' from package 'libpar-packer-perl' (universe)
 Command 'pack' from package 'liballegro4-dev' (universe)
 Command 'pmark' from package 'libxgks-dev' (universe)
 Command 'ark' from package 'ark' (universe)
 Command 'pork' from package 'pork' (universe)
 Command 'par2' from package 'par2' (universe)
 Command 'spark' from package 'spark' (universe)
 Command 'mark' from package 'mailutils-mh' (universe)
 Command 'mark' from package 'nmh' (universe)
 Command 'par' from package 'par' (universe)
park: command not found
[1]+  Exit 1                  git co yard
```

how can I checkout to this branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is interpreting the `&` character. You can prevent the shell from doing so by surrounding it with quotes:

```
$ git checkout 'yard&park'
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the name with quotes

```
git checkout "yard&park"
```

This will allow you to check it out.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Specify name in quotes

```
git checkout "yard&park"
```